# Swift using ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I am parsing json from server. I am getting 4 values in json so I created model class

```
class PriceData: Mappable {
var buy: Double?
var sell: Double?
var spot_price: NSNumber?
var timestamp: String?
var timesStampDt: Date?

required init?(map: Map) {
    //
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    buy <- map["buy"]
    sell <- map["sell"]
    spot_price <- map["spot_price"]
    timestamp <- map["timestamp"]
    print(String(describing: GlobalMethods.dateFormat(dt: timestamp!)))
    timesStampDt <- map[String(describing: GlobalMethods.dateFormat(dt:            
 timestamp!))]
}
}
```

I am geting timestamp as string type but I need to covert into date while parsing so I converted timeStamp to date by using this method and

```
   static func dateFormat(dt: String) -> Date{
    let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date1  = formatter.date(from: dt)
    print("date:\(String(describing: date1))")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let resultTime = formatter.date(from: dt)
    return resultTime!
}
```

but I when passing the converted date to "timesStampDt" in mapping func
the value of timesStampDt is nil.[image]

Comment: In Swift 4 ObjectMapper became obsolete in favor of `Codable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use Transform method from object mapper. Check DateTransform class and use it like follows.

```
timesStampDt <- (map["timestamp"], DateTransform())
```

Tis will transform your timestamp to Date. You can further study the transform class and make any Object Transform for yourself, This is very flexible

Comment: This Is what I changed while mapping  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        if let dateString = map["timestamp"].currentValue as? String, let _date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
            timesStampDt = _date as NSDate
        }

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you simply let JSONDecoder handle the date parsing? You can set [your format](https://gist.github.com/stinger/7140232de1e0a4ea1f72b39b2052beb3) on the decoder to configure in what format you get your date with so the decoder knows how to decode it.

Doing it with `JSONDecoder` and `Codable` makes parse code a lot cleaner.

[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4) is a Codable tutorial for you to read.